df (mis)calculation with efa models in lavaan
I've been working on some functionality to wrap EFA scripting in lavaan, and noticed some df's that seemed off. I'm now wondering if I'm goofing/overlooking something, or rather, if something unexpected or errant is going on by using cfa() to fit these models (as done, at one point, in the EFA lavaan tutorial/example)
To use the same example (and if comfortable), installing the package I develop (which has the built-in data set im using):
install.packages("dySEM")

library(dySEM)
library(lavaan)

dat <- commitmentQ

fac1.script <- "
#Measurement Model

#Loadings
efa('efa')*f1 =~ sat.g.1_1+sat.g.1_2+sat.g.1_3+sat.g.1_4+sat.g.1_5 + sat.g.2_1+sat.g.2_2+sat.g.2_3+sat.g.2_4+sat.g.2_5

#Residual Variances
sat.g.1_1 ~~ sat.g.1_1
sat.g.1_2 ~~ sat.g.1_2
sat.g.1_3 ~~ sat.g.1_3
sat.g.1_4 ~~ sat.g.1_4
sat.g.1_5 ~~ sat.g.1_5

sat.g.2_1 ~~ sat.g.2_1
sat.g.2_2 ~~ sat.g.2_2
sat.g.2_3 ~~ sat.g.2_3
sat.g.2_4 ~~ sat.g.2_4
sat.g.2_5 ~~ sat.g.2_5

#Residual Covariances
sat.g.1_1 ~~ sat.g.2_1
sat.g.1_2 ~~ sat.g.2_2
sat.g.1_3 ~~ sat.g.2_3
sat.g.1_4 ~~ sat.g.2_4
sat.g.1_5 ~~ sat.g.2_5 
"

fac2.script <- "
#Measurement Model

#Loadings
efa("efa")*f1 +
efa("efa")*f2 =~ sat.g.1_1 + sat.g.1_2 + sat.g.1_3 + sat.g.1_4 + sat.g.1_5 + sat.g.2_1 + sat.g.2_2 + sat.g.2_3 + sat.g.2_4 + sat.g.2_5

#Residual Variances
sat.g.1_1 ~~ sat.g.1_1
sat.g.1_2 ~~ sat.g.1_2
sat.g.1_3 ~~ sat.g.1_3
sat.g.1_4 ~~ sat.g.1_4
sat.g.1_5 ~~ sat.g.1_5

sat.g.2_1 ~~ sat.g.2_1
sat.g.2_2 ~~ sat.g.2_2
sat.g.2_3 ~~ sat.g.2_3
sat.g.2_4 ~~ sat.g.2_4
sat.g.2_5 ~~ sat.g.2_5

#Residual Covariances
sat.g.1_1 ~~ sat.g.2_1
sat.g.1_2 ~~ sat.g.2_2
sat.g.1_3 ~~ sat.g.2_3
sat.g.1_4 ~~ sat.g.2_4
sat.g.1_5 ~~ sat.g.2_5 
"

fac3.script <- "
#Measurement Model

#Loadings
efa("efa")*f1 +
efa("efa")*f2 +
efa("efa")*f3 =~ sat.g.1_1 + sat.g.1_2 + sat.g.1_3 + sat.g.1_4 + sat.g.1_5 + sat.g.2_1 + sat.g.2_2 + sat.g.2_3 + sat.g.2_4 + sat.g.2_5

#Residual Variances
sat.g.1_1 ~~ sat.g.1_1
sat.g.1_2 ~~ sat.g.1_2
sat.g.1_3 ~~ sat.g.1_3
sat.g.1_4 ~~ sat.g.1_4
sat.g.1_5 ~~ sat.g.1_5

sat.g.2_1 ~~ sat.g.2_1
sat.g.2_2 ~~ sat.g.2_2
sat.g.2_3 ~~ sat.g.2_3
sat.g.2_4 ~~ sat.g.2_4
sat.g.2_5 ~~ sat.g.2_5

#Residual Covariances
sat.g.1_1 ~~ sat.g.2_1
sat.g.1_2 ~~ sat.g.2_2
sat.g.1_3 ~~ sat.g.2_3
sat.g.1_4 ~~ sat.g.2_4
sat.g.1_5 ~~ sat.g.2_5 
"

When I fit these...(Defaulting to geomin rotation, so factor correlations are estimated):
sat.defa1.fit <- cfa(fac1.script , data = commitmentQ)
sat.defa2.fit <- cfa(fac2.script , data = commitmentQ)
sat.defa3.fit <- cfa(fac3.script , data = commitmentQ)

And compare them...:
anova(sat.defa1.fit, sat.defa2.fit, sat.defa3.fit)

I get:

30 df for 1-factor,
21 df for 2-factor, and
13 df for 3-factor

This checks out for the 1-factor model. Following ye ol' p(p+1)/2 formula:
knowns: 10(10+1)/2 = 55
1-factor model is estimating 10 factor loadings, 10 residual variances, 5 residual covariances = 25 estimates
df for 1-factor: 55 - 25 = 30.
So far, so good.
To move to a 2-factor, then, would involve estimation of 10 additional loadings (onto second factor) and a correlation between F1 and F2. So estimating 11 additional things (36)
df for 2-factor should be 55 - 36 = 19
But for this model, anova() shows df 21 (df diff of 9, instead of 11)
The problem seems to compound for the 3-factor model:
Should be estimating 48 elements (adding 20 new factor loadings vs. 1 factor model + 3 factor correlations), so df should be 7, while anova() returns 13.
Any idea of what's going on here? I've looked at nrow() of parameterEstimates() from each model (subtracting of fixed variances for identification/scale-setting) and it corresponds to my counts of # of ests for each model.
I've also disabled meanstructure estimation (not that is was estimating anyways) just in case, to no avail.


Defaulting to geomin rotation, so factor correlations are estimated

They are not estimated.  They are fixed to 0 during estimation.  They become nonzero after being rotated, and their SEs are provided by the delta method.  So both the point and SE estimates of factor correlations are only implied (after oblique rotation) by the unrotated estimated loadings.  This is analogous to estimating a CFA with the first loading fixed to 1, but the standardizedSolution() provides a nonzero standardized loading and its delta-method SE.

a 2-factor, then, would involve estimation of 10 additional loadings (onto second factor)

No, there are 10 items, and they all load onto the first factor. But additional identification constraints are necessary for subsequent factors.  Sunthud's efaUnrotate() function (in old versions of semTools) applied a constraint on all loadings that was similar to effects-coding (average = 1), but lavaan applies a much simpler algorithm:

For the second factor, fix loading = 0 for Item 1
For the third factor, fix loadings = 0 for Item 1 and 2
For the fourth factor, fix loadings = 0 for Item 1--3
and so on until no additional factors can be identified

So your 2-factor model only estimates 9 additional loadings, no factor correlation, resulting in $df=21$.
Then your 3-factor model estimates 8 additional loadings (still no factor correlations), resulting in $df=13$.
I don't think there is sufficient documentation about this yet, but you could always learn a lot about your EFA/ESEM model by leaving it unrotated for initial inspection.
FYI, in case you are looking to impose equality constraints on your loadings, those would only hold during estimation (i.e., in the unrotated solution): https://doi.org/10.1111/bmsp.12336

Really informative, @Terrence, thank you! The analogy to MV + standardizedSolution() helps to clarify this a lot, and I'll be sure to dig into the paper you linked. As you say, documentation here might be nice (then again, many probably don't check this sort of thing), but I'll be sure to include some of this in my pkg's documentation + link to this answer.
